# PHP script + MySQL only returning one row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem where the PHP page only returns one row instead of a couple.
It should return multiple rows nicely in the table, but it doesn't..
If I delete the appearing row, it will display the next one (but still one).

UPDATE:
Sorry, I didn't explain about which MySQL query the question is.
It is about "SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 2..."

PS: I know I should **not** use MySQL and instead PDO or MySQLi, but I'll change this soon.

```
     <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school WHERE schoolid = '$schoolvanleerling'"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $schoolnaam = $row['schoolnaam'];

     } ?>.

    </p><br>
    <h3>Actieve tutors</h3>
                <table class="demotable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Naam tutor</th>
                                    <th>Klas tutor</th>
                                    <th>Vakken tutor</th>
                                    <th>Rating tutor</th>
                                    <th>Cijfer tutor</th>
                                    <th>Acties</th>
                                </tr>
<? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = '2' AND bijles_school = '$schoolvanleerling' ORDER BY name ASC"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="profiel.php?id=<? echo $row['id'];?>"><? echo $row['name'];?></a></td>
                                        <td><? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klas WHERE id = '$row[klas]'"); while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?><? echo $rowa['naam'];?><? }?></td>
                                        <td> <? $bijlesvakkenn = explode(",", $row['bijles_tutor']); 
     foreach ($bijlesvakkenn as $value) {
    ?>
    <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vakken WHERE id = '$value' ORDER BY naam ASC"); while($rowvak = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
     echo $rowvak['naam'];?><br><? } } ?></td>
                                        <td><? // echo getRating($row['id']); ?></td>
                                        <td>nog geen cijfer beschikbaar</td>
                                        <td>- Deactiveer Tutor<br>- <a href="mailto:<? echo $row['email'];?>">Contact opnemen</a></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <?  } ?>
                                </table>
    <br><br>
    <h3>Niet goedgekeurde tutors</h3>
                    <table class="demotable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Naam tutor</th>
                                        <th>Klas tutor</th>
                                        <th>Vakken tutor</th>
                                        <th>Rating tutor</th>
                                        <th>Cijfer tutor</th>
                                        <th>Acties</th>
                                    </tr>
    <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = '1' AND bijles_school = '$schoolvanleerling' ORDER BY

 name ASC"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><? echo $row['name'];?></td>
                                    <td><? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klas WHERE id = '$row[klas]'"); while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?><? echo $rowa['naam'];?><? }?></td>
                                    <td> <? $bijlesvakkenn = explode(",", $row['bijles_tutor']); 
 foreach ($bijlesvakkenn as $value) {

?>
<? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vakken WHERE id = '$value' ORDER BY naam ASC"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 echo $row['naam'];?><br><? } } ?></td>
                                    <td><? echo getRating($row['id']); ?></td>
                                    <td>8</td>
                                    <td>- Deactiveer Tutor<br>- Contact opnemen</td>
                                </tr>

                                <?  } ?>
                            </table>
<?php } ?>
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE:
*change is that I'm no longer using $result more than once*

```
 <? $resultschool = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school WHERE schoolid = '$schoolvanleerling'"); while($rowschool = mysql_fetch_array($resultschool)){
echo $schoolnaam = $rowschool['schoolnaam'];
 } ?>.
</p><br>
<h3>Actieve tutors</h3>
                <table class="demotable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Naam tutor</th>
                                    <th>Klas tutor</th>
                                    <th>Vakken tutor</th>
                                    <th>Rating tutor</th>
                                    <th>Cijfer tutor</th>
                                    <th>Acties</th>
                                </tr>
<? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 2 AND bijles_school = '$schoolvanleerling' ORDER BY name ASC"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="profiel.php?id=<? echo $row['id'];?>"><? echo $row['name'];?></a></td>
                                    <td><? $resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klas WHERE id = '$row[klas]'"); while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)){ ?><? echo $rowa['naam'];?><? }?></td>
                                    <td> <? $bijlesvakkenn = explode(",", $row['bijles_tutor']); 
 foreach ($bijlesvakkenn as $value) {

?>
<? $resultvak = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vakken WHERE id = '$value' ORDER BY naam ASC"); while($rowvak = mysql_fetch_array($resultvak)){ 
 echo $rowvak['naam'];?><br><? } } ?></td>
                                    <td><? // echo getRating($row['id']); ?></td>
                                    <td>nog geen cijfer beschikbaar</td>
                                    <td>- <a href="mijnprofiel.php?do=manageschool&action=deactivatetutor&id=<? echo $row['id'];?>">Deactiveer Tutor</a><br>- <a href="mailto:<? echo $row['email'];?>">Contact opnemen</a></td>
                                </tr>

                                <?  } ?>
```

Comment: You're using `$result` twice.

Comment: Please [format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) your code properly so it'd be easier for us to read and understand what's wrong.

Comment: @MikeB I corrected that, but that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @AmalMurali I added about which part of the code the question is about.

Comment: @user1857116 Did you correct it in the question? Your querying from users and assigning it to $result. Then inside the loop you query for klas and assign it to $result. Then inside that loop you query vakken and assign it to $result. You seem to understand the need to isolate each result from each query because you're using $row, $rowa, and $rowvak yet the same $result variable for all three.

Comment: @MikeB You're correct, I forget one other $result.. Well thanks! I should stop copying code the whole time haha

Comment: Can you update your code with what you *actually* have? After these comments I have no idea what has been corrected and what hasnt

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, use mysqli or PDO

Comment: I don't really see a problem with the code. If you run that query in phpmyadmin (or manually) does it return more than one result?

Answer (score 0):

You Just Replace this Code from your code I think Its Working

```
   <? $resultschool = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM school WHERE schoolid = '$schoolvanleerling'");

   while($rowschool = mysql_fetch_array($resultschool))
   {
     $schoolnaam = $rowschool['schoolnaam'];
     } ?>
    </p><br>
     <h3>Actieve tutors</h3>
            <table class="demotable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Naam tutor</th>
                                <th>Klas tutor</th>
                                <th>Vakken tutor</th>
                                <th>Rating tutor</th>
                                <th>Cijfer tutor</th>
                                <th>Acties</th>
                            </tr>
      <? $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 2 AND bijles_school = '$schoolvanleerling' ORDER BY name ASC");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="profiel.php?id=<? echo $row['id'];?>"><?            echo $row['name'];?></a></td>
                                <td><? $resulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM klas WHERE id = '$row[klas]'");
                                 while($rowa = mysql_fetch_array($resulta)){
                                  echo $rowa['naam'];
                                   }?></td>
                                <td> <? $bijlesvakkenn = explode(",", $row['bijles_tutor']); 
                                foreach ($bijlesvakkenn as $value) {
                                                                     $resultvak = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vakken WHERE id = '$value' ORDER BY naam ASC"); 
                                                                     while($rowvak = mysql_fetch_array($resultvak)){ 
                                                                        echo $rowvak['naam']."<br>";
                                                                         } 
                                                                    } ?></td>
                                <td><? // echo getRating($row['id']); ?></td>
                                <td>nog geen cijfer beschikbaar</td>
                                <td><a href="mijnprofiel.php?do=manageschool&action=deactivatetutor&id=<? echo $row['id'];?>">Deactiveer Tutor</a><br>- <a href="mailto:<? echo $row['email'];?>">Contact opnemen</a></td>
                            </tr>

                            <?  
                        } ?>
```